# best approximation of $\sqrt[3]{8.1}$ using cubic function

Tags: calculus

> Approximate value of $\sqrt[3]{8.1}$ using linear approximation of $g(x)=(x+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

What i try:

Linear approximation of $f(x)$ at $=a$ is given by

$$L(x)=g(a)+g'(a)(x-a)$$

$$L(x)=\sqrt[3]{a+1}+\sqrt[3]{(a+1)^{-2}}(x-a)$$

I did not understand what should i take $a$ so that i can approximate $\sqrt[3]{8.1}.$

Help me please

Comment: I think that the $1$ is probably a typo for $0.1$

Comment: To @Token Toucan options given as $a=6,7,8,9.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $a=0$. If $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{1+x}$, then $f'(0)  =1/3$ so that $f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{3}x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$. The best linear approxiamtion to $\sqrt[3]{8.1} = 2\sqrt[3]{1+0.1/8}$ is then 
$$2+\frac{2}{3}\cdot0.0125=2.0083...$$

Comment: Thanks Zachary.But option given as $a=6,7,8,9$

Comment: How did the question itself define $a$? I would then take $a=8$ and notice that $\sqrt[3]{8+0.1} = 2\sqrt[3]{1+0.1/8}$, which is what I did in my calculation and then use the linear approximation of $\sqrt[3]{1+x}$ near $ x=0$.

Comment: Thanks Zachary actually it is multiple correct option with $4$ options like $a=6,7,8,9$ .You mean  we have to take linear approximation of $g(x)$ at $x=a=8.$ Then using what u have used in last line $(8.1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=2\bigg(1+\frac{1}{80}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: Yes, that is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you meant to write $g(x) = \sqrt{x + 0.1}$ instead of $\sqrt{x+1}$? Using this function, you'd take a linear approximation to $\sqrt{8.1}$ about $a=8$.

Comment: No hdighfan actually it is $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+1}$.